# Powershell outputs CSV data into multiple lines instead of single line

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with data about some users and ids, and i have to add to each entry a mail formed by their name.surname@domain. While it manages to print it into a file, when i open the file it's formatted so each one of the columns gets sepparated into an entry each.

```
$origin = Get-Content $file

$origin = foreach{ $line= $_.Split(",")

$line+","+line[0].ToLower()+"."+line[1].ToLower()+"@"+$domain

} | Set-Content $outputfile
```

If the file has 1 entry like

```
john,doe,1234
```

the output of the file should be

```
john,doe,1234,john.doe@mail.com
```

but instead it prints each attribute as a column

```
john
doe
1234
@
mail.com
```

Am i using the wrong kind of print or is the loop wrong?

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` to read in the data, if there is no header, specify with the `-Header` parameter. Read [Get-Help Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: The code you posted is also invalid, missing `$` signs and 2nd line must be `$origin | foreach{ $line= $_.Split(",")` Also `$line` is an array which due to the split contains 3 elements [0..2], if you output an array, elements are by default on sep. lines. So it should be `$_+","+$line[0].ToLower()+"."+$line[1].ToLower()+"@"+$domain`

Answer (score 0):

The file is a .csv file. Take advantage of that.

```
Import-Csv -Path './joe.csv' -Header fname, lname, empnum |
    Select-Object -Property *, @{Name='email';Expression={$_.fname + '.' + $_.lname + '@mail.com'}} |
    Export-Csv -Path './joe2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```